# React component autobinding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript, autosuggest

I am new to React and javascript and trying to use moroshko's component [react-autosuggest](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest), but failing to get event handlers to bind correctly. I'm writing in coffeescript, but will paste compiled javascript too.

```
define [
  'jquery',
  'react',
  'reactdom',
  'autosuggest'
], (jQuery, React, ReactDOM, Autosuggest) ->
  escapeRegexCharacters = (str) ->
    str.replace /[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'
  getSuggestions = (praxes, value) ->
    if value == ""
      return []
    val = escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim())
    regex = new RegExp('^' + val, 'i')
    praxes.filter((prax) => regex.test(prax.species))
  getPraxSpecies = (prax) ->
    prax.species
  renderSpecies = (prax) ->
    React.createElement("span", null, getPraxSpecies(prax))

  Species = React.createClass
    getInitialState: ->
      value: ''
      suggestions: getSuggestions(@props.praxes, '')

    onChange: (event, {newValue}) ->
      @setState({value: newValue})

    onSuggestionsUpdateRequested:  ({value}) ->
      @setState {suggestions: getSuggestions(@props.praxes, value)}

    render: ->
      inputProps =
        placeholder: "Choose a species"
        value: ''
        onChange: @onChange
      autosuggest = React.createFactory Autosuggest
      React.DOM.div {key: 'autosugg', className: 'praxis'},
        autosuggest {
          key: 'autoSp',
          suggestions: @state.suggestions,
          onSuggestionsUpdateRequested: @onSuggestionsUpdateRequested,
          getSuggestionValue: getPraxSpecies,
          renderSuggestion: renderSpecies,
          inputProps: inputProps
        }
    Species
```

or coffeescript above compiled to javascript below:

```
(function() {
  define(['jquery', 'react', 'reactdom', 'autosuggest'], function(jQuery, React, ReactDOM, Autosuggest) {
    var Species, escapeRegexCharacters, getPraxSpecies, getSuggestions, renderSpecies;
    escapeRegexCharacters = function(str) {
      return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    };
    getSuggestions = function(praxes, value) {
      var regex, val;
      if (value === "") {
        return [];
      }
      val = escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());
      regex = new RegExp('^' + val, 'i');
      return praxes.filter((function(_this) {
        return function(prax) {
          return regex.test(prax.species);
        };
      })(this));
    };
    getPraxSpecies = function(prax) {
      return prax.species;
    };
    renderSpecies = function(prax) {
      return React.createElement("span", null, getPraxSpecies(prax));
    };
    return Species = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          value: '',
          suggestions: getSuggestions(this.props.praxes, '')
        };
      },
  onChange: function(event, _arg) {
    var newValue;
    newValue = _arg.newValue;
    return this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  },
      onSuggestionsUpdateRequested: function(_arg) {
        var value;
        value = _arg.value;
        return this.setState({
          suggestions: getSuggestions(this.props.praxes, value)
        });
      },
      render: function() {
        var autosuggest, inputProps;
        inputProps = {
          placeholder: "Choose a species",
          value: '',
          onChange: this.onChange
        };
        autosuggest = React.createFactory(Autosuggest);
        console.log('this: ' + this);
        return React.DOM.div({
          key: 'autosugg',
          className: 'praxis'
        }, autosuggest({
          key: 'autoSp',
          suggestions: this.state.suggestions,
          onSuggestionsUpdateRequested: this.onSuggestionsUpdateRequested,
          getSuggestionValue: getPraxSpecies,
          renderSuggestion: renderSpecies,
          inputProps: inputProps
        }));
      }
    }, Species);
  });

}).call(this);
```

The autosuggest component displays properly initially, accepts input, and calls onChange and onSuggestionsUpdateRequested functions in that order. State is updated, but possibly not attached to the correct component. The autosuggest then repaints exactly as initially (i.e. value='').

Substituting fat-arrow => for -> in defining onChange results in an error: `Uncaught TypeError: _this.setState is not a function`

I have also tried using the coding style of moroshko's example without success. Clearly, I am missing something ...

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript.  It looks like you pasted the coffeescript in both locations.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. Replaced 2nd cs w/ js.

Comment: yeah but I'm not sure the js you posted matches the CoffeeScript.  The JS for `onChange` looks like you used the fat arrow?  You definitely do not want that

Comment: Suggested reading: http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: another mistake, now fixed. ->  onChange is      onChange: function(event, _arg) {
        var newValue;
        newValue = _arg.newValue;
        return this.setState({
          value: newValue
        });
      },

Comment: Thank you Andy, for the blog post. " we lose "autobinding," which is confusing to new users" is correct. Your suggested solution 4 "use createClass" seems to have difficulties with a an ES6 class like react-autosuggest, and I'm using webjars so I suppose the webpack problem you mention is operating when I try the ES6 style. This is a mess.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in your `inputProps`.  You need to use `this.state.value`:

```
 inputProps =
    placeholder: "Choose a species"
    value: ''
    onChange: @onChange
```

to:

```
 inputProps =
    placeholder: "Choose a species"
    value: @state.value
    onChange: @onChange
```

Comment: Thank you, Brandon. That fixes it. Much appreciated.